# Infragistics UltraGrid: LoadOnDemand feature not working properly

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using the Infragistics Windows Ultragrid, version 7.3. I'm trying to use an UltraDataSource along with the LoadOnDemand mode. I have three bands defined: root, child and grandchild.

When I click on the first row, it requests the data for the child band but also requests the grandchildren rows under the first child.

Why does it happen?

I believed those items shouldn't be requested unless I click on the child band.

Answer (score 0):

More info on this issue. I have spotted the ultraDataSource's InitializeRowsCollection event is raised when I'm setting up the rows number for the root band, i.e.

ultraDataSource1.Rows.SetCount(collection.Count);

In this point I haven't added yet the actual rows to the root band. Why is it requesting the items for the child band?

Answer (score 0):

If I set up the bands and the data for the root band before everything, then the InitializeRowsCollection event is not raised until I do ultraGrid1.DataSource = ultraDataSource1;

But once again it is raised for the Child and GrandChild Band.

Answer (score 0):

We have workarounded this by using the ultragrid's InitializeRowsCollection event rather than the UltraDataSource's. This event is fired when expected.

Regards.